# Image Processing in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to modify this to perform a simplified gray-scaling calculation.  For each pixel, calculate the average of the r, b, b values of the color image, and set all three r, g, b values to this average.  Then, I need to write a setColor function tht expects two arguments: an image and an RGB tuple containing 3 integers.  The setColor function should set every pixel in the image to the RGB tuple color.  It needs to be 200 pixels wide by 100 pixels tall, allowing the user to enter three integers for the RGB values, printing the prompt "Close the image window to continue", calls setColor with the image and the user specified color tuple, and drawing the image.

```
from images import Image

def grayscale(image):
    "Converts the argument image to grayscale."""
    for y in xrange(image.getHeight()):
        (r, g, b) = image.getPixel(x, y)    
        r = int(r * 0.299)
        g = int(g * 0.587)
        b = int(b * 0.114)
        lum = r + g + b
        image.setPixel(x, y, (lum, lum, lum))

def main(filename = "smokey.gif")"
    image = Image(filename)
    print "Close the image window to continue."
    image.draw()
    graysclae(image)
    print "Close the image window to quit."
    image.draw()

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing what the question is.

BTW, you have a typo in main() - graysclae(image)

Comment: Oops..I wasn't done.  The question above is what needs to be done: modifying the program to perform a simple gray-scaling calculation, and then writing a setColor function.  I'm not sure how to do either one.